# Can't bind to 'data-html2canvas-ignore' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'

Tags: angular, html2canvas, html2pdf

I am using `jspdf` to export page to pdf. I want to hide few elements before exporting it pdf. So  I am using `html2canvas-ignore` property in html tag.

It works fine if I define it directly in html tag ( i.e `html2canvas-ignore ='true'`).

But I want to use it based on condition so I am trying to do property binding.
but if I try to  to `[data-html2canvas-ignore]="condition"` its throwing following error.

***Can't bind to 'data-html2canvas-ignore' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'.
1. If 'data-html2canvas-ignore' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.***

How can I add `html2canvas-ignore` property based on condition?

Answer (score 0):

Since html2canvas-ignore is a propertytry to add the value of your condition like this `html2canvas-ignore = "{{ condition }}"`
You may have written the logic in .ts file to determine the condition's value. Try this and let me know if that works.

Comment: Tried that. It throws - .Can't bind to 'html2canvas-ignore' since it isn't a known property of html.